# Optimal order placement of a good across different places when cost and quantity is unknown

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for some help in devising/researching an algorithm. I have come up with some solutions on my own, but would like some guidance as to whether there exists a more formal/robust/mathematical solution.

The problem can be stated as follows:

I would like to purchase X amount of a good at as low of a price as possible.

There are Y amount of places that this good is available for sale

The price and quantity available at each particular place are initially unknown

There exists a probability that the price of a good at a place will change as a function of the amount of time since the order was placed. The distribution is skewed to the right, with a mean u

The simple solution is to query all places. Wait for all price and available quantity to be discovered. And then purchase goods from lowest price to highest price until I accumulate the desired amount.

However, this implementation leads to the problem where the price of a good can change while I am waiting for all of the quotes to come in. For example, if the price discovery from one location takes too long, it will lag the entire order process. During this time the price could have changed at a place where an order could have been completed (since the price and quantity were known and acceptable, although maybe not optimal). This will result in a worse price when compared to simply not waiting at all.

At the opposite end, I could simply fulfill an order if the price is deemed reasonable when it is discovered. This approach runs the risk that there is a better price available, and had I waited for its price to be discovered, I could have gotten my good for cheaper.

A hybrid of the two strategies would involve waiting a fixed amount of time for prices/quantities to come in, processing those, and then processing the rest as they continue to come in. I feel this is the optimal algorithm, but I am not sure how to more mathematically define the amount of time I should be waiting.

Is there a robust mathematical solution that will define the amount of time I should be waiting? Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE! You might be interested in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit (I'm not sure if that is relevant or not).

Comment: This is a very interesting analogue, thank you! It seems the only difference is that in the formal problem definition, only one secretary is chosen, as opposed to the best x